# Radon measure determined by the intersection of half lines in the plane

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, dirac-delta

Consider a vector $r$ in the euclidian plane $\mathbb R^2$ and two unit vectors $u,v\in\mathbb U$ ($\mathbb U$ is the unit circle). Let $s>0$ be a real number. I am looking for an expression of the following distribution on $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^+\times\mathbb U\times\mathbb U$
$$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\int_0^s \delta^{(2)}(r-tu+(s-t)v)\mathrm dt\tag1$$
where $\delta^{(2)}$ is a 2-dimensional Dirac distribution, which is defined by $\delta^{(2)}((x,y))=\delta(x)\delta(y)$.
I exclude the cases $u=v$ and $u=-v$.

Here is what I have done so far. It's detailed and hence rather long...

I have considered the following problem : there are two points $A$ and $B$
from where start two half lines with unit vectors $u$ and $v$ (see the figure below) and such that $\overrightarrow{AB}=r$.

[image: sketch of the intersection problem]

The half-lines can cross, but under a condition that is to be determined.
A point on the half-line $(A,u)$ is of the form $A+xu$ with $x\geq0$. Similarly a point on $(B,v)$ is of the form $B+yv$, with $y\geq0$. The intersection is given by the equation $A+xu=B+yv$, $$xu=r+yv\tag2.$$
If we write (2) as $r-xu+yv=0$, we see that problem (1) is related to the intersection equation (2) with the extra condition $x+y=s$.

As the vectors $u$ and $v$ are not colinear, it is possible to solve (2) by taking the scalar products with both $u$ and $v$ :
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccccc}
x&=&r\cdot u&+&y\,u\cdot v\\
x\,u\cdot v&=&r\cdot v&+&y \end{array}\right.$$
We get
$$x=\frac{r\cdot u-(r\cdot v)(u\cdot v)}{1-(u\cdot v)^2}\qquad 
y=\frac{r\cdot v-(r\cdot u)(u\cdot v)}{1-(u\cdot v)^2}.\tag3$$
and we conclude that the half-lines intersect if $r\cdot u\geq(r\cdot v)(u\cdot v)$ and $r\cdot v\geq(r\cdot u)(u\cdot v)$. If these conditions are
not fulfilled, the integral (1) vanishes.

Supposing these conditions are satisfied, we can see that we have to impose
$x+y=s$ which can simplified into
$$r\cdot u+r\cdot v-(1+u\cdot v)s=0.\tag4$$ 
Interestingly the conditions $x\geq0$ and $y\geq0$ expressed with (3) and  combined with the condition (4) give $s-r\cdot u\geq0$ and $s-r\cdot v\geq 0$. From there I am not so sure: I have tried to write $\mu$ as 
$$\mu(r,s,u,v)=f(r,s,u,v)\delta\big(r\cdot u+r\cdot v-(1+u\cdot v)s\big)\Theta(s-r\cdot u)\Theta(s-r\cdot v)\tag5$$
where $f$ is a regular function ($\Theta$ is the Heaviside step function).
I have integrated this expression with respect to $v$
and obtained
$$\int\mu(r,s,u,v)\mathrm dv=2f(r,s,u,v_1)\frac{\Theta(s-|r|)}{\sqrt{r^2-(r\cdot u)^2}}$$ where $v_1$ is such that $(r-su)\cdot v_1=s-r\cdot u$.
I have also integrated (1) with respect to $v$ and got
$$\int\mu(r,s,u,v)\mathrm dv=\frac{\Theta(s-|r|)}{s-r\cdot u}.$$
I am wondering if I can
deduce $f(r,s,u,v)$ from these computations. Can anyone (who went throught all of this) give me a little hint ? Thanks.

Comment: It is not obvious to me how knowledge of $f$ would address your original question. Are you interested in the form of $f$ as a final result, or is this just one way of arriving at an expression for $\mu$ ?

Comment: @Justpassingby. I am ultimately interested in $\mu$. My question is focused on $f$ because, if my thoughts are correct, $\mu$ is of the form (5). Of course if (5) is wrong, $f$ is irrelevant.

Comment: $\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{u^1+v^1} \frac{1}{u^2+v^2} \delta(\frac{x^1+sv^1}{u^1+v^1}-\frac{x^2+sv^2}{u^2+v^2})$ ?

Comment: @Pete. Could you give more details please ?

Comment: This is just a very quick feeling ... developping your delta functions in a limiting process using generalized functions like the gate one. In the notation $r=(x^1,x^2)$, $u=(u^1,u^2)$, $v=(v^1,v^2)$. Maybe is this too simple.

Comment: I think that there is a sign error in the solution for $y$ which slightly changes the argument of the delta function in (5).

Comment: @Justpassingby. You are right, it changes signs and inequalities. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $r = (x_1,x_2)$, $u=(u_1,u_2)$, $v=(v_1,v_2)$ be the vectors 
once analyzed in the canonical basis of the plane $\mathbb R^2$.
We set $u+v=w=(w_1,w_2)$ and $r+sv=y=(y_1,y_2)$.

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\int_{0}^s \delta^{(2)}(r-tu+(s-t)v)dt=\int_{0}^s \delta^{(2)}(y-tw)dt$

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\int_{0}^s \delta(y_1-tw_1) \delta(y_2-tw_2) dt$

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\int_{0}^s \delta(y_1-tw_1) \delta(y_2-tw_2) dt$

We set $t_1 = y_1/w_1$ and $t_2=y_2/w_2$

Using the property of Dirac measure $\delta(ax)=\frac{1}{|a|}\delta(x)$
and symetry $\delta(-x)=\delta(x)$.

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\int_{0}^s \delta(t-t_1) \delta(t-t_2) dt$

Consider now an expression of the dirac distribution as 
the limit of, let say, a family of gaussian  distributions ("generalized functions")

$\delta(x) =\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+} \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}$

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\lim_{\sigma_1\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}} \lim_{\sigma_1\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^s \exp{-\frac{(t-t_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}} \exp{-\frac{(t-t_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}} dt$

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\lim_{\sigma_1\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{\sigma_2\sqrt{2\pi}} \lim_{\sigma_1\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{\sigma_1\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{0}^s \exp{-[\frac{(t-t_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}}+\frac{(t-t_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}] dt$

From now on we will use only one "small parameter" $\sigma=\sigma_1=\sigma_2$

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{\sigma^22\pi}\int_{0}^s \exp{-[\frac{(t-t_1)^2+(t-t_2)^2}{2\sigma^2}]} dt$

The integral has primitive,

$-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}\sigma\exp{-\frac{(t_1-t_2)^2}{4 \sigma^2}}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_0^s$

Hence,

$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}\frac{\sqrt 2}{4}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp{-\frac{(\frac{t_1-t_2}{\sqrt2})^2}{2 \sigma^2}}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0=\frac{1}{|w_1w_2|}\delta(t_1-t_2) \lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{2}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0 $

Now we can discuss the limit of the error function in the primitive.

- $t_1+t_2\neq 0\ \wedge\  t_1+t_2-2s\neq 0$ then $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0 = 1 - 1 = 0$

Then $\mu(r,s,u,v)=0$.

- $t_1+t_2 =0\ \wedge\  t_1+t_2-2s\neq 0$ then $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0 = 0-1=-1$

Then $\mu(r,s,u,v)=-\frac{1}{2|w_1w_2|}\delta(t_1-t_2)$.

- $t_1+t_2 \neq 0\ \wedge\  t_1+t_2-2s= 0$ then $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0 = 1-0= 1$

Then $\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac{1}{2|w_1w_2|}\delta(t_1-t_2)$.

- $t_1+t_2 = 0\ \wedge\  t_1+t_2-2s= 0$ then $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0+}[\mathrm{erf}(\frac{t_1+t_2-2t}{2\sigma})]_s^0 = 0-0= 0$

Then $\mu(r,s,u,v)=0$.

You can back-substitute then $t_1,t_2$, $w_1$, $w_2$ in the solutions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it deserves the bounty. I was indeed on a wrong track. One could use $$\lim_{\sigma\to0}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac x\sigma\right)=\operatorname{sign}(x)$$ where $\operatorname{sign}(x)=-1,\,0$ or $+1$ if $x<0$, $x=0$, $>0$ respectively. This yields $$\mu(r,s,u,v)=\frac12\left(\operatorname{sign}(t_1+t_2)-\operatorname{sign}(t_1+t_2-2s)\right)\delta(w\times y),$$
where $\times$ is the cross product, which is, in two dimensions, a scalar equal to the determinant $w_1y_2-w_2y_1$.

Comment: Elegant. Thanks for the bounty.